# Exibir valores dos campos de tabela SQLite no Console

Tags: java, android

Estou usando o seguinte trecho de código para retornar no console Android Studio os valores dos campos de um DB:

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS pessoas(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, nome VARCHAR, idade INT(3))");    

Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM pessoas", null);

//Recuperando os índices das colunas
int indiceColunaId = cursor.getColumnIndex("id");
int indiceColunaNome = cursor.getColumnIndex("nome");
int indiceColunaIdade = cursor.getColumnIndex("idade");

// Movendo o cursor para o primeiro item
cursor.moveToFirst();

while (cursor != null)
{

     // Recuperando os valores armazenados no cursor
     Log.i("Resultado - id: ", cursor.getString(indiceColunaId));
     Log.i("Resultado - nome: ", cursor.getString(indiceColunaNome));
     Log.i("Resultado - idade: ", cursor.getString(indiceColunaIdade));


     // movendo o cursor para o próximo item
     cursor.moveToNext();
}
```

Infelizmente sem sucesso, não recebo retorno ao incluir as linhas:

```
int indiceColunaId = cursor.getColumnIndex("id");
```

e

```
Log.i("Resultado - id: ", cursor.getString(indiceColunaId));
```

A tabela está populada, o simples fato de remover

> Log.i("Resultado - id: ", cursor.getString(indiceColunaId));

faz com que a saída dos demais campos apareçam normalmente. E ainda não entendi onde está o meu erro.

Desde já grato pela ajuda !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A coluna **id** é do tipo `INTEGER`.

Em vez de

```
cursor.getString(indiceColunaId)
```

use

```
cursor.getInt(indiceColunaId)
```

Como `Log.i()` espera uma String tem de converter antes de usar:

```
Log.i("Resultado - id: ", String.valueOf(cursor.getInt(indiceColunaId)));
```